# regex number OR period

Tags: regex, character-class

I am having a problem with a regex.  I am trying to find the combination of a Letter and digit/period/hyphen.  So it will always start with a capital letter, followed by either a digit, period or hyphen, followed by a space.  So all of these should work

- `D7`
- `A.`
- `H-`

But these shouldn't

- `GJ`
- `G6.` (No space after the second param)

At the moment I am trying this without success

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{1}|\.\s
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{1}\d{1}|\.\s`

Comment: with the statement `followed by a space` you mean just a space character or any character represented by `\s` ? Because it means space, tab or enter characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a character class:

```
(?<= |^)[A-Z][\d.-](?= |$)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/MHJCk8XGIF)

Minor FYI: A hyphen at the start or end of a character class is a literal hyphen (not a range).

Other minor FYI: The quantifier `{1}` is redundant/implied - it makes no difference if you add it, so don't (regex is hard enough to read already).

Comment: @Jorge it was a typo - my eyesight isn't that great :/ Fixed now - thanks.

Comment: Brilliant, the first one seems to work.  I have changed it slightly to add a white space at the end `[A-Z][\d.-]\s`

Comment: @NickPrice Remember that the `\s` control character means not only the space, it also means an enter or a tab character so the answer provided by  Bohemia (first one) doesn't need any changes since it already contains the space at the end of the regex.

Comment: The problem is, the one Bohemia provided picks up on something like QF8406 (or it does on the online regex testers, picks up F8).  I need it to match if it is only 2 characters long, so the space was helping with this.  Is there another way around this?

Comment: @NickPrice I have added look arounds to assert it's a "word" that stands alone. See linked demo.